# describing an action of repetitive mentioning of some urgent need

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What's the right word in English to describe an action of repetitive mentioning of some urgent need? For example,

> This politician began to show up on TV every so often
>   **_______________-ing the urgent need to** make reforms to our economy.

1) sounding the urgent need

2) alarming the urgent need

3) trumpeting the urgent need

4) whistle-blowing the urgent need

5) ?

Answer (score 1):

None of your options describe a repetitive act.

The best fit would be the word "repeating".

The sentence structure you used in your example can lead to ambiguity.  To correct this, I would suggest a different sentence structure.

To build on your example:

> The politician would *periodically* show up on TV to *emphasize* the need for Parliament to reform the economy.
>
> The politician would *occasionally* show up on TV to *stress* the need for Parliament to reform the economy.
>
> The politician would *routinely* show up on TV to *articulate* the need for Parliament to reform the economy.